# JavaScript Slideshow(No jQuery or any other library)

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I want to make simple slideshow which works automatically(no buttons). The images should slide from bottom to top. I have explained the things after the code.

HTmL:

```
<ul id="imgSlider1">
    There are images here in <li> tags
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = initAll;

function initAll(){
    var img = document.getElementById("imgSlider1");

    if((parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(img).top)) == -1160){
    img.style.top = 290 +"px";}

    var i = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(img).top);   
    var j = i-290;

    slideIt(i, j, img);
}

function slideIt(initTop, finalTop, target){
    if(initTop == finalTop){
    window.setTimeout(initAll, 10000);
    }

    target.style.top = (initTop - 1)+"px";

    var presentTop = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(target).top);
    window.setTimeout(function(){ slideIt(presentTop, finalTop, this)},20)
}
```

What I have tried to do here:
The 'initAll()' function gets the 'top' of the list and 'i' is assigned that value. Variable 'j'
 is assigned the 'i-290' (because 290px is the height of each image). Now 'i', 'j', and the target object (which is the list of images here) are passed to the next function 'slideIt()'. 'slideIt()' function subtracts '1px' each time from the 'top' of the target object and is called over and over again till 'top' becomes equal to 'finalTop'(which is value assigned to 'j'). when this condition is satisfied, the 'initAll' function is called back after 10 seconds.

Now, Why isn't this code working?

Console says: "Cannot set property 'top' of undefined"

Comment: `,20` is in the wrong place.

Comment: @SLaks I corrected it. But its still continuously moving. It should stop for 10 secs when image changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the idea described below could help you achieve what you want.
(See also this **[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/V6DEW/)**.)

The main idea is to scroll 1 pixel at a time until a pre-determined "check-point" is reached. The check-points are the offsets of the images relative to the slider container (i.e. the `<ul>` element in your case).

```
function slideIt(slider, ...) {
    ...
    setTimeout(function() {
        slider.scrollTop += 1;
        slideIt(slider, ...);
    }, 20);
    ...
}
```

When a check-point is reached, you determine the next check-point (next image's offset relative to the slider container) and continute the scrolling process.

```
...
/* Reached new image ("check-point") */
nextIdx++;
nextTop = (nextIdx < imgs.length) 
    ? imgs[nextIdx].offsetTop - slider.offsetTop     // <-- next check-point
    : -1;     // <-- last image reached, just scroll to the bottom    
setTimeout(function() {
    slider.scrollTop += 1;
    slideIt(slider, nextTop, ...);
}, newImgDelay);     // <-- stay longer (e.g. 10s) 
                     //     to let the user see the new image
...
```

Comment: NP. (In case you are using code from the jsFiddle demo, I slightly modified it in order to take into account user's manually scrolling down (past the next check-point).)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){ slideIt(presentTop, finalTop, this), 20})
```

To be:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){ slideIt(presentTop, finalTop, target), 20})
```

I'm not sure why you used `this`, but `this` it is likely equal to `window` at that point, which means you are passing `window` into `slideIt()` where it expects a reference to your image. So then at the line of code that has:

```
target.style.top
```

...because `target` is now `window` it is actually trying to do:

```
window.style.top
```

...and `window.style` is `undefined`. Resulting in the error you mentioned, "Cannot set property 'top' of undefined".

Comment: I changed it and that worked. But not the way I wanted it to work. What I wanted was the when images slides, and the next image should stay on the screen for  10 seconds. But thats not happening. Its sliding continuously.